# How to pass files name in array and then iterating for the file upload functionality in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to create a for loop where I will pass all the files in the list using beforeEach and then I want to iterate the list in order to upload file via api call.

I have placed all my files under cypress/fixture/files folder.

I want to add the file that is under the fixture/files folder into the array like below:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.fixture('files/').as('files')
});
```

And then I want to iterate the files array to upload the files via api call.

I used below code to iterate:

```
cy.wrap(files).each((index) => {
  const fileName = files[index];
```

When I try to use above code I get below error. I am not sure if I am using the right approach.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solves the issue, but the way you use the alias is not correct. You need to `cy.wait('@files')` to get the value of the alias. `cy.get('@files')` is also correct syntax but will not work here since `cy.fixture()` reads from the disk (so you must wait for it to complete).

Since you use the files straight after loading them, get rid of the alias and use a `.then()` to wait

```
/*
  Fixture file contains:
  { 
    "uploadFilePng": "files/cypressFileUpload.png", 
    "uploadFileDmg": "files/cypressFileUpload.dmg", 
    ...
  }
*/

cy.fixture('files/cypressFileUpload').then(files => {
  const fileNames = Object.values(files);
  cy.wrap(fileNames).each(fileName => {
    console.log(fileName); // should see "files/cypressFileUpload.png", "files/cypressFileUpload.dmg"
    ...
```

Comment: I tried the said approach but I still get error 

"cy.each() can only operate on an array like subject. Your subject was: @files

Because this error occurred during a before each hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: Upload File"

Comment: It will depend on what you have in `files/cypressFileUpload`. Presume it is a json array?

Comment: Yes its a json array with content:

{
    "uploadFilePng": "files/cypressFileUpload.png",
    "uploadFileDmg": "files/cypressFileUpload.dmg",
    "uploadFilePkg": "files/cypressFileUpload.pkg",
    "uploadFileHtm": "files/cypressFileUpload.html",
    "uploadFileDocx": "files/cypressFileUpload.docx",
    "uploadFileJar": "files/cypressFileUpload.jar",
    "uploadFilePdf": "files/cypressFileUpload.pdf",
    "uploadFileJpg": "files/cypressFileUpload.jpg",
    "uploadFileXlsx": "files/cypressFileUpload.xlsx",
    "uploadFileZip": "files/cypressFileUpload.zip"
}

Comment: Ok, actually that's a json object -  slightly different handling.